# Google Assistant Raspberry Pi Problem | hotword not working

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, google-assistant-sdk

I am new to raspberry and python and I've installed the Google Assistant using this tutorial https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-google-assistant/ on my Raspberry Pi 4 B using Raspbian.

This works fine:

```
googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk
```

Testing it, I get the following errors:

```
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ google-assistant-demo --project-id XXX
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/env/bin/google-assistant-demo", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/assistant/library/__main__.py", line 119, in main
    raise Exception('Missing --device-model-id option')
Exception: Missing --device-model-id option
```

Also running "`googlesamples-assistant-hotword`" just gives me a memory access error.

I am trying to get it to work handsfree on boot so I used `sudo systemctl status assistant.service` which gives me:

```
● assistant.service - Google Assistant
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/assistant.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-12-29 20:11:46 CET; 2s ago
  Process: 10343 ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/pi/start_assistant.sh (code=exited, s
 Main PID: 10343 (code=exited, status=139)

Dez 29 20:11:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Google Assistant.
Dez 29 20:11:46 raspberrypi bash[10343]: /home/pi/start_assistant.sh: Zeile 4: 1
Dez 29 20:11:46 raspberrypi systemd[1]: assistant.service: Main process exited, 
Dez 29 20:11:46 raspberrypi systemd[1]: assistant.service: Failed with result 'e
lines 1-10/10 (END)
```

I think the errors are probably related.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hi.

Di you manage to solve this issue ? stuck in the same place ...
If so, please elaborate how did you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/register-device) to create a device model ID and then pass that argument when you run the project.